# Is there an efficient way to reactively import text into R shiny modal dialog?

Tags: r, shiny, modal-dialog

My App in R Shiny uses modal dialog boxes to give the user lengthy explanations. As you can see in the below MWE, there is a lot of text. In the complete App, not shown here, there are many other text explanations that results in very cluttered, hard to read code in both the UI and Server sections. Instead of how it's done in this MWE, is there a way to reactively import the text when the user clicks the action button (for example, importing straight from a Word file saved in the same directory)?

If the above isn't possible, is there a way to modularize lengthy text like this, moving it into another section (like the function declaration section) where it doesn't clutter up the UI or Server sections?

I have seen some R packages that make the dialog boxes and related functions very beautiful. I´m not looking for any more beauty than that when running this MWE. I just need a way to efficiently compartmentalize the text.

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(style = "margin-top:20px;margin-left:10px;margin-right:10px",
                
      # --- Creates header row at top of page
    fluidRow
      (column(12, 
              actionButton("explain1",
                           strong("Gettyburg Address"),
                           icon = icon("info-circle"),
                           style="color: #fff;background-color:#337ab7;font-size:19px;
                                  position:fixed;width: 95vw;")
      ) # closes column
  ), # closes fluid row
)  # fluid page

server <- function(input, output) {
  observeEvent(input$explain1, {
    showModal(modalDialog(
      title = "Background and text of the Gettysburg Address",
      tags$ul(
        tags$li("Gettysburg Address is a speech that Abraham Lincoln delivered at 
                the dedication of the Soldiers' National Cemetery in Gettysburg, PA."), 
        tags$li("On the afternoon of November 19, 1863."),
        tags$li("Four and a half months after the Union armies defeated those of the 
                Confederacy at the Battle of Gettysburg."),
        tags$li("It is one of the best-known speeches in American history.")),
      tags$p(strong("Text of speech:")),
      
      "Four score and seven years ago our fathers brought forth upon this continent, 
      a new nation, conceived in Liberty, and dedicated to the proposition that all men 
      are created equal.",tags$p(""),
      "Now we are engaged in a great civil war, testing whether that nation, or any 
      nation so conceived and so dedicated, can long endure. We are met on a great 
      battle-field of that war. We have come to dedicate a portion of that field, as 
      a final resting place for those who here gave their lives that that nation might 
      live. It is altogether fitting and proper that we should do this.",tags$p(""),
      "",tags$p(""),
      "But, in a larger sense, we can not dedicate—we can not consecrate—we can not 
      hallow—this ground. The brave men, living and dead, who struggled here, have 
      consecrated it, far above our poor power to add or detract. The world will little 
      note, nor long remember what we say here, but it can never forget what they did here. 
      It is for us the living, rather, to be dedicated here to the unfinished work which 
      they who fought here have thus far so nobly advanced. It is rather for us to be here 
      dedicated to the great task remaining before us—that from these honored dead we take 
      increased devotion to that cause for which they gave the last full measure of devotion
      — that we here highly resolve that these dead shall not have died in vain—that this 
      nation, under God, shall have a new birth of freedom—and that government of the 
      people, by the people, for the people, shall not perish from the earth."
    )) # closes showModal
  })   # closes observeEvent
} # closes server

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: save it as a global variable, e.g. in a global.R file next to server and ui file.

Comment: Thank you Roman, that works. I did more digging, asked around some more, and will present the complete working code above. For any fellow neophytes stuck in the same place.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In response to Roman's suggestion, I moved the text into a separate Global.R file. It is now out of my App file and is much cleaner and easier to follow. For any others stuck in the same place, below is the complete working code for the MWE above. I saved both under the same directory.

App.R file:

```
library(shiny)
source("./Global.R")

ui <- fluidPage(style = "margin-top:20px",
  fluidRow
    (column(12, 
          actionButton("explain1",
          strong("Gettyburg Address"),
          icon = icon("info-circle"),
          style="font-size:19px;
                 position:fixed")
     ) # closes column
  ), # closes fluid row
)  # fluid page

server <- function(input, output) {
  AbeLincoln(input,"explain1")
} # closes server

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Global.R file (more text than necessary for a MWE but I LOVE that speech):

```
AbeLincoln <- function(input,value){

observeEvent(input[[value]], {  
    showModal(modalDialog(  
      
      title = "Background and text of the Gettysburg Address",
      
      tags$ul(
        
        tags$li("Gettysburg Address is a speech that Abraham Lincoln delivered at 
                 the dedication of the Soldiers' National Cemetery in Gettysburg, PA."), 
        tags$li("On the afternoon of November 19, 1863."),
        tags$li("Four and a half months after the Union armies defeated those of the 
                 Confederacy at the Battle of Gettysburg."),
        tags$li("It is one of the best-known speeches in American history.")),
      
      tags$p(strong("Text of speech:")),
      
        "Four score and seven years ago our fathers brought forth upon this continent, 
        a new nation, conceived in Liberty, and dedicated to the proposition that all men 
        are created equal.",tags$p(""),
        "Now we are engaged in a great civil war, testing whether that nation, or any 
        nation so conceived and so dedicated, can long endure. We are met on a great 
        battle-field of that war. We have come to dedicate a portion of that field, as 
        a final resting place for those who here gave their lives that that nation might 
        live. It is altogether fitting and proper that we should do this.",tags$p(""),
      
        "",tags$p(""),
      
        "But, in a larger sense, we can not dedicate—we can not consecrate—we can not 
        hallow—this ground. The brave men, living and dead, who struggled here, have 
        consecrated it, far above our poor power to add or detract. The world will little 
        note, nor long remember what we say here, but it can never forget what they did here. 
        It is for us the living, rather, to be dedicated here to the unfinished work which 
        they who fought here have thus far so nobly advanced. It is rather for us to be here 
        dedicated to the great task remaining before us—that from these honored dead we take 
        increased devotion to that cause for which they gave the last full measure of devotion
        — that we here highly resolve that these dead shall not have died in vain—that this 
        nation, under God, shall have a new birth of freedom—and that government of the 
        people, by the people, for the people, shall not perish from the earth."
      
      ) # close modal dialog
    ) # close show modal 
  }) # close observe event
} # close function
```

Comment: there is no need to `source("./Global.R")` in the server file. In addition you can call all libraries only in the global file.